# Kendo dropdownlist Optional label not displayed

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

If the value binded to a kendo dropdownlist is empty(Count =0) OptionalLabel specified is not displayed instead a blank dropdownlist is displayed

```Razor
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("TransactionTypeId")
            .BindTo((IEnumerable<KPMG.LER.ViewModel
            .General.NameIdPair>)ViewData["TransactionTypes"])
            .DataTextField("Name")
            .DataValueField("Id")
            .OptionLabel("--Select--")
```

Is there a way to display Optional Label always

Comment: now you can do this declaratively as well ... <select name="fieldName"
                                k-data-text-field="'name'"
                                k-data-value-field="'key'"
                                k-option-label= "'Select One ...'" 
                                k-data-source="model.custom_fields"

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript control function which is fired with databound event.

```js
if (....) // control if datasource count = 0 
    $("#TransactionTypeId").data("kendoDropDownList").text(--Select--);
```

this is not an option label but it looks like option label to users :)